# C++ functor unexpected behavior in for_each

Tags: c++, stl, functor

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class accum
{
public:
    int sum;
    accum()
    {
        sum = 0;
    }
    void operator() (int a)
    {
        sum += a;
        printf("sum=%d\n",sum);
    }
};

int main()
{
     int ari[] = {2,8,5,9,1};
     vector<int> vi(&ari[0], &ari[5]);
     accum f;
     for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), f);
     printf("final sum : %d\n", f.sum);
}
```

I expected the sum to be `25`, but it prints `0`. Why does `f` remain unchanged? Can somebody give me a detailed account of what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) takes its functor by *value*, not by reference. It's operating internally on a copy of `f` and the one you pass in remains unchanged. It does *return* the functor back to you, so you could just overwrite yours:

```
accum f = std::for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), accum());
```

Or, sticking with C++03, have `accum` take a reference:

```
struct accum {
    int& sum;
    // rest as before, fixing the constructor
};

int sum = 0;
std::for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), accum(sum));
printf("final sum : %d\n", sum);
```

Although perhaps you might just want [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
int sum = std::accumulate(vi.begin(), vi.end(), 0);
```

Or, in C++11, `for_each` with a lambda:

```
int sum = 0;
std::for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), [&](int a){ sum += a; });
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.